# How to get rid of "A new flutter project" in link previews?

Tags: flutter, web, deployment, telegram, preview

I've created [a flutter web project](https://wikipoll.b4a.app/#/).

In it, I've updated the description in pubspec.yaml and the title + description in the index.html inside the "web" folder.

However, the preview of the webpage in telegram continues to display the old description: "A new Flutter project." (and the original project's title) not the ones set in the index.html file neither pubspec.yaml:

[image]

Where should I update the project's description, so telegram stops displaying the old one?

The description is properly displayed in WhatsApp and Discord... :
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Search** for this meta tag in your index.html

```
<meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
```

Change it to whatever you like

Comment: I changed that already and didn't affect Telegram's description. However, not no description is shown at all. Maybe some kind of cache was used by Telegram. But I don't understand why, now, no description appears at all using Telegram, but it works flawlessly using WhatsApp.